# Need an explanation about stack frames - why value of this local variable isn't removed?

Tags: c, function, callstack, stack-frame

I've got a question about this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    int a = 22;
}

void foo(void)
{
    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}

int main(void)
{
    bar();
    foo();
}
```

Why is it displaying 22 like it was assigned in bar function and not the garbage data?

Shouldn't stack frame of bar function be removed from call stack (so do "a" variable) after bar function was terminated? I cannot find any decent explanation (probably, I just don't search hard enough) how call stack/stack frame really works. Can you please help me understand?

Comment: It _is_ displaying garbage. You throw an apple into your trash can. Then you look into the trash can and the apple is still there. It's still an apple, even if it is in the garbage. What you see here is _undefined bahaviour_ (google that term). The printf in foo just displays the content of the uninitialized variable and it happens that the 22 from the previous call to bar is still there. But you might as well get another value.

Comment: The stack frame is just created/destroyed by moving the stack pointer. Function exit doesn't 'delete' the stack frame (e.g. zero it), Whatever was there is still there.

Comment: "garbage" in this sense means that the C language does not specify what the value is.  That's a property of execution context, not something that you can determine from the value itself.

Comment: "Undefined behavior" means that anything can happen. "Print `22` twice" is one possible value of "anything".

Comment: "Why is it displaying 22" It is displaying 0 on my compiler. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: To make this even more clear (i.e. it's not the "same" value), in either function [but _not_ both functions], we could rename `a` to `b` and the result would be the same. The stack frames for `foo` and `bar` overlap and start at the _same_ address on the stack (at different points in time). It is the offset within each function's stack frame where the compiler decides to store the variable. Because there is only one variable, the compiler chooses to put them at the same offset in their respective stack frames.

Comment: So stack frame from bar function is never deleted from call stack (just stack pointer is moved out from that frame) so next function could just get the variable from that extinguished previous stack frame? @pmacfarlane

Comment: @chlebastian yes, this is exactly what happens here on your platform. Be aware that this behaviour depends on your platform, your compiler, your compiler version, the compiler settings used and possibly a few other things.

Comment: The result probably depends on the optimization options you use. An optimizing compiler might find out that the assignment to a local variable in function `bar` has no effect and generate an empty function or no code at all for this function.

Comment: @chlebastian "deleted" means that the memory is no longer legal for you to use. Nothing else. The memory is obviously still physically in your computer. DRAM capacitors physically are set to SOME value always - until it gets overwritten with another value. A common misconception is that discarded data will be overwritten with something (like zeroes) - but C never promised it. If you want your data to be private, you have to erase it yourself.